# Postman: How to open a browser window/redirect from a pre-request script?

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have a pre-request script in Postman that retrieves an internal identifier from an API based on a `CLIENT_COMMON_NAME` variable. To authenticate, I am using my browser cookies with Postman Interceptor and Interceptor Bridge.

The pre-request script works fine when logged in, but for convenience, I want it to redirect me to the internal login page `https://auth.example.com` if I'm currently not logged in.

My code:

```js
const BASE_URL = "https://auth.example.com";
const API_CLIENT = pm.globals.get("API_CLIENT");
pm.cookies.jar().getAll(BASE_URL, function (error, cookies) {
  pm.sendRequest(
    {
      url: `${BASE_URL}/identitygen?user=${API_CLIENT}`,
      cookies: cookies,
    },
    function (err, res) {
      try {
        err === null &&
          pm.globals.set("TECHNICAL_API_IDENTITY", res.json().identity);
      } catch (error) {
        // How can I redirect to https://auth.example.com here?
      }
    }
  );
});
```

What would be the best way to redirect to the login page in this scenario? I'm not sure how to achieve this using JavaScript in the Postman pre-request script. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that it occurs in the catch block, you just use the sendRequest method again: pm.sendRequest(`${BASE_URL}`);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pm.request` to redirect to the login page:

```js
const BASE_URL = "https://auth.example.com";
const API_CLIENT = pm.globals.get("API_CLIENT");
pm.cookies.jar().getAll(BASE_URL, function (error, cookies) {
  pm.sendRequest(
    {
      url: `${BASE_URL}/identitygen?user=${API_CLIENT}`,
      cookies: cookies,
    },
    function (err, res) {
      try {
        if (err === null) {
          pm.globals.set("TECHNICAL_API_IDENTITY", res.json().identity);
        } else {
          // Handle error and redirect to login page
          pm.request.redirect(`${BASE_URL}/login`);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle error and redirect to login page
        pm.request.redirect(`${BASE_URL}/login`);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

I added an else block after checking if `err === null`.
If an error occurs during the API request, it will execute the code inside the else block and redirect to the login page using `pm.request.redirect`.

Similarly, if an error occurs while parsing the response JSON, it will also redirect to the login page.

Comment: unfortunately postman says `TypeError: pm.request.redirect is not a function`